# RPi zero W watchdog doesn't start

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, watchdog, raspberry-pi-zero

i have enabled watchdog on RPi zero W but when i would like to start (sudo systemctl start watchdog ) exit with error message
Code: Select all

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl start watchdog
Job for watchdog.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status watchdog.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

systemctl status :
Code: Select all

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status watchdog
● watchdog.service - watchdog daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2021-10-26 04:15:49 IDT; 5s ago
Process: 817 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ -z "${watchdog_module}" ] || [ "${watchdog_module}" = "none" ] || /sbin/modprobe $watchdog_module (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 819 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c [ $run_watchdog != 1 ] || exec /usr/sbin/watchdog $watchdog_options (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
Process: 820 ExecStopPost=/bin/sh -c [ $run_wd_keepalive != 1 ] || false (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 26 04:15:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting watchdog daemon...
Oct 26 04:15:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: watchdog.service: Control process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Oct 26 04:15:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: watchdog.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 26 04:15:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: watchdog.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Oct 26 04:15:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start watchdog daemon.
Oct 26 04:15:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: watchdog.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.

Any idea about this issue ?
Thanks